# Docker ADD giving error "No source files were specified"

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Dockerfile is failing on the following line:

```
ADD ./test-web-app/build/libs/test-web*.war /app/test-web.war
```

> Error  Step 8/29 : COPY ./test-web-app/build/libs/test-web*.war
>   /app/micro-service.war No source files were specified

This is the first time I am working on Docker builds. How do I debug this issue? Is there a way to echo if the host file is existing by a command ?

Comment: It would be helpful to have a full(er) listing of the Dockerfile and directory structure you're working with.

Answer (score 5):

be sure that the path of the file is accessible where the Dockerfile is. When you run the build, the `.` folder is where the Dockerfile is. So you directory structure has to be something similar to this:

```
.
..
Dockerfile
test-web-app (folder)
```

To be sure that the war file is accessible try to list the file (on your host machine) for example.

```
$ ls ./test-web-app/build/libs/test-web*.war
```

Comment: my dockerfile is actually two level deep.
~/test-web$ docker build -t xyz . -f infra/docker/Dockerfile 
the war is ~/test-web/test-web-app/build/libs folder

Comment: i had a typo issue. i was doing the wrong ls and i had the wrong path in the docker file. thanks for the response